# assignment followed by boolean operator

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I've come across statements like these where an assignment (in this case to the first column of a numpy data array) is followed by a boolean operator. Such as this for example.

```
indices = data[:,1] == 1
```

How would what happens here be explained in psuedocode, and what type of output is generated from this statement?

In this case this was followed by this stament:

```
jan_data = data[indices]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data[:,1] == 1` is an expression that will evaluate to a value.  This value will be assigned to `indices`.  Using parentheses, you can think of it as `indices = (data[:,1] == 1)`.  It is not "an assignment followed by a boolean operator".  It is an assignment whose right-hand side is an expression containing a boolean operator.  You can assign the result of `a == b` just like you can assign the result of `a + b`.

Types get to define what sort of value is returned by such comparisons.  In this case, I suspect `data` is a numpy array, and comparing numpy arrays gives you another numpy array of boolean values, with True where the condition was true and False where it was false.  So if `data[:,1]` was something like `[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`, the result of `data[:,1] == 1` would be `[True, False, False, False, True]`, and this is the value that would be assigned to `indices`.

Comment: I don't want to say anything, but if I define `data` as a list if integers (`data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`) and try `data[:,1] == 1`, I get a `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`. Python 2.7.3.

Comment: @oopcode: Yes, that's why I said I suspect `data` here is a numpy array (not a list).

Comment: @oopcode When you use `data = np.array([[1,3,4,5],[4,6,8,9]])` You will get the boolean array as output.